# Javascript random cell background color change

Tags: javascript, colors, html-table, cell, background-color

I am trying to create a table. `ruudud.value` is a value from `<select>`. But while this function is creating a table, I want it to place some random yellow cells in it.
This is a small school project and this code is part of a code which should createbattleship game.

Also if possible. when it does create a random yellow cell, then could it also paint the next cell yellow? (to create a 2 cell ship).

```
function addTable() {

    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    table.border = '1';

    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * ruudud.value) + 0);
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * ruudud.value) + 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < ruudud.value; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        console.log(x + "," + y);
        for (var j = 0; j < ruudud.value; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('TD');
            var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
            td.width = '50';
            td.height = '50';
            td.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            td.setAttribute("onClick", "colorChange(this)")
            td.innerHTML = (i + "," + j);
            if (td[i].innerHTML == (x + "," + y)) {
                td[i].setAttribute("style", "background:yellow;");

            }
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
}
function colorChange(tdObj) {
tdObj.style.backgroundColor = "green";}
```

example2:

```
function addTable() {

var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");


var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
table.border='1';

var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * ruudud.value) + 0);
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * ruudud.value) + 0);

for (var i=0; i<ruudud.value; i++){
   var tr = document.createElement('TR');
   tableBody.appendChild(tr);
 console.log(x + ","+y);  
   for (var j=0; j<ruudud.value; j++){
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        var td2 = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        var i = 0, tds = td.length;
        td.width='50';
        td.height='50';
        td.style.backgroundColor="white";
        td.setAttribute("onClick", "colorChange(this)")
        td.innerHTML = (i +","+ j);
        if(td2[i].innerHTML == (x + "," + y)) {
            td2[i].setAttribute("style", "background:yellow;");

        }
        tr.appendChild(td);
        }
   }
myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
}
function colorChange(tdObj) {
tdObj.style.backgroundColor = "green";}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both the cases, you are selecting the `td` element before it is appended to the DOM. You don't need to select it again, you can simply apply style to the `td` element when you create it. Here's a slight modification to your code. I have also added a condition to add two-cell ships like you asked.

```
function addTable(double) {
    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    table.border = '1';

    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * ruudud.value) + 0);
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * ruudud.value) + 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < ruudud.value; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        //console.log(x + "," + y);
        for (var j = 0; j < ruudud.value; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.width = '50';
            td.height = '50';
            td.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            td.setAttribute("onClick", "colorChange(this)");
            td.innerHTML = (i + "," + j);
            if (x === i && y === j) {
                td.setAttribute("style", "background:yellow;");
            }
            // If you need to enable two-cell ships, pass true to the function
            // You can allow horizontal or vertical cells by changing x and ys in the equality checks below
            if(double){
                if(y+1 < ruudud.value){
                    if(x === i && y+1 === j){
                        td.setAttribute("style", "background:yellow;");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(x === i && y-1 === j){
                        td.setAttribute("style", "background:yellow;");
                    }
                }
            }
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
}

function colorChange(tdObj) {
tdObj.style.backgroundColor = "green";}

addTable(true);
```

Comment: It says ruudud not defined now. And i didn't quite get how to make them double. Also one question, is it possible to set how many yellow cells it does. Lets say I make 10x10 grid. How to set it so it would create 7 yellow double cells?

Comment: You can set a variable `var ruudud = {value:10};` or something. Based on your code, I assumed you were getting that variable from elsewhere. To get two yellow cells, call the function as `addTable(true)`, otherwise call as `addTable()`. I don't quite understand the part where you ask "7 yellow double cells".

Comment: Hmm addTable is set as true already, but only singular cells appear. And by that 7 cells appear I mean a grid, where the code places 7 yellow cells randomly. At the moment is places just 1  random yellow cell in a 10x10 table for example.

Comment: Checkout this jsFiddle for the original solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tcesbn6n/ (single and two adjacent cells). Also check out this solution to address your variable number of random cells to be colored differently: http://jsfiddle.net/e0hvgr41/. Pass the number in the function call.

Comment: my html looks like this: <div id="myDynamicTable"><input type="button" id="create" value="Click here" onclick="addTable()"></div> Now when I launch the function for many random cells then it says: TypeError: myTableDiv is null

Comment: Its hard to tell without looking at your HTML. This works as expected for me: http://jsfiddle.net/e0hvgr41/1/.